# SQL compare phone numbers from previous quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to compare phone numbers from 2 different quarters. What I need to do is compare phone numbers from the reporting quarter (previous quarter) to the quarter prior. We are looking to return only new clients so we want SQL to return the data where phone numbers from the reporting quarter do NOT match any numbers from the previous quarter. We are using SQL Server. Current data ex:

```
Year|Quarter|PhoneNumber
-------------------------
2022|   2   | 1111111111
2022|   2   | 2222222222
2022|   2   | 3333333333
2022|   1   | 2222222222

What we want returned:
Year|Quarter|PhoneNumber
------------------------
2022|   2   | 1111111111
2022|   2   | 3333333333
```

So just the numbers that are in quarter 2 but not in quarter 1 needs to be returned in the above example.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Your table names do not help others understand your schema. Are we to assume that rows in CRecNT (is that really meaningful alias?) are those from a particular year? Or do you need to filter for a specific year? Personally [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) leaps to my mind rather than OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Apologies for not producing a minimal reproduceable example. i'm new to StackOverflow and didn't really understand what that was by I get it now and my next question I will be sure to do this. For now I just removed the code completely since I just need to understand the concept of how to do this. The code was honestly irrelevant. I was able to use your example below @Yitzhak Khabinsky and get what I needed. Apologies for not properly following rules and your points are well taken. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is not provided. So I am shooting from the hip.

Please try the following solution. You can use it as a conceptual example.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Year INT, QUARTER INT, PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (Year, QUARTER, PhoneNumber) VALUES
(2022, 2, '1111111111'),
(2022, 2, '2222222222'),
(2022, 2, '3333333333'),
(2022, 1, '2222222222');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT PhoneNumber FROM @tbl
    WHERE QUARTER = 2
    EXCEPT
    SELECT PhoneNumber FROM @tbl
    WHERE QUARTER = 1
)
SELECT t.* 
FROM @tbl AS t
INNER JOIN rs ON t.PhoneNumber = rs.PhoneNumber;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+---------+-------------+
| ID | Year | QUARTER | PhoneNumber |
+----+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | 2022 |       2 |  1111111111 |
|  3 | 2022 |       2 |  3333333333 |
+----+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for your answer. I just really needed to understand the concept of how to do this and you provided:) I have accepted your answer.